# encode javascript URL

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Iam forming a URL in JavaScript and passing this URL on click of a custom button,i want to encode the parameters, some of the parameters having value like &, I tried with string.replace() and encodeURI..

```
var url = '/apex/GSDCSCAccountLocationSearch?srmid=' + '{!pse__Proj__c.Id}'+
    '&cmpname=' +'{!pse__Proj__c.pse__Account__r.name}' +
    '&city=' +'{! pse__Proj__c.PSA_Location_City__c}' +
    '&state=' +'{! pse__Proj__c.PSA_Location_State__c}' +
    '&zip=' +'{!pse__Proj__c.PSA_Location_Zip__c}'+
    '&renderSaveButton=TRUE'+'&country='+CountryCode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're merging from Visualforce, so you need to encode before it gets merged into the code. Use JSINHTMLENCODE to get your parameters properly encoded. Also, since you're merging the values directly into your code, there's no need for all that string concatenation. Finally, you could probably just use URLFOR to get your URL properly formatted.

```
var url = '{!JSINHTMLENCODE(URLFOR($Page.GSDCSCAccountLocationSearch, null, [srmid=pse__Proj__c.Id, cmpname= pse__Proj__c.pse__Account__r.name, city= pse__Proj__c.PSA_Location_City__c, state= pse__Proj__c.PSA_Location_State__c, zip= pse__Proj__c.PSA_Location_Zip__c, renderSaveButton=TRUE]))}& country='+CountryCode;
```

This should take care of all the relevant escaping for you.

Comment: tried the above code getting the syntax error.Error: Syntax error. Found '$Page.'

Comment: @srini My phone inserted an extra space in `$Page.GSDCSCAccountLocationSearch` (after the period). I've fixed this.